# Configure Nuget to download packages which are not part of any project but are required in repository

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, nuget, nuget-package

I have configured nuget to download all packages, which are used in all projects of solution, but i have few more nuget packages, which are not part of any project/proejct's package file but we need it to download for other functionality.

Can you please help me to configure nuget/pre-build, so that it can also automatically download few other packages which are not part of any project's package.config file.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a stand-alone packages.config file in the root of the solution dir or in a standard location and use "Nuget.exe install packages.config " command in your pre-build event to install the packages.